# getClass() method returning different class than expected

Tags: java, junit

I am removing duplicates of path from list using:

```
paths.removeAll(Collections.singleton(path));
```

I am running above code from TestClass.java running Junit test cases.

Equals and hashcode methods consider string value inside path object.

Equals method fails in below code.

```
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
```

Even though all objects inside paths list are of same type Path. Above code fails to match class name. I saw it was giving class name as junit class name TestClass$5$1$1 as first value and TestClass$5$1$2 as second value, hence it fails.

Anything I am doint wrong here? Thanks in advance.

I am creating list of paths using below code.

```
Paths paths = new Paths(){
    {
        setPaths(new ArrayList<Path>(){
            {
                add(new Path(){
                    {
                        setValue("c:\\\\test");
                    }
                });
                add(new Path(){
                    {
                        setValue("c:\\\\test1");
                    }
                });
                add(new Path(){
                    {
                        setValue("c:\\\\test1");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

If I create list "paths" by normal java code, equal method works properly and it removes duplicate path.

Comment: What is `Path`? How are you instantiating it? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Path is class with field value inside it. Equals and hashcode are written on this field.

Comment: Can you show the line where you assign a value to the `path` variable?  And the line where you create the object that it references?

Comment: I know it's a class. We need to see the class and how you're instantiating it.

Comment: When you've added the relevant code, you can vote to reopen

Comment: @Bohemian Please reopen.

Comment: With `new Path() { }` you create an anonymous subclass of `Path` (you define similar anonymous subclasses of `Paths` and `ArrayList`)

Comment: @shmosel 'tis done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code creates an anonymous class of `Path` :

```
add(new Path(){
    {
        setValue("c:\\\\test");
    }
});
```

And according the actual  `Path.equals()` snippet you posted, to check the type compatibility, it doesn't rely on `instanceof` but `getClass()` :

```
 if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
    return false;
 }
```

So these two objects are not equal :

```
Path p1 = new Path(){
    {
        setValue("c:\\\\test");
    }
 }

Path p2 = Paths.get(("c:\\\\test");
```

As these are from two distinct classes : `Path` class and a anonymous `Path` class.

As workaround you could change the Path `equals()`to use `instanceof` such as :

```
 if (!(obj instanceof Path))
    return false;
 }
```

But in fact, you don't need to create anonymous classes.
You should rather take advantage of constructors to initialize your objects rather than using initializers.
By introducing `Paths(List<Path> pathes)` 
 and `Path(String path)` constructors, you could so write something as :

```
Paths paths = new Paths(
    new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        new Path("c:\\\\test"),
        new Path("c:\\\\test1"),
        new Path("c:\\\\test1"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a distinct anonymous class for each object you're instantiating. Just create them normally, without a custom initializer block:

```
Path path1 = new Path();
Path path2 = new Path();
Path path3 = new Path();
path1.setValue("c:\\\\test");
path2.setValue("c:\\\\test1");
path3.setValue("c:\\\\test1");

Paths paths = new Paths();
paths.setPaths(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(path1, path2, path3)));
```

You can reduce the verbosity of creating and initializing each `Path` object by adding a constructor:

```
class Path {
    private String value;

    public Path(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    //...
}
```

Same for `Paths`:

```
class Paths {
    private List<Path> paths;

    public Paths(List<Path> paths) {
        this.paths = paths;
    }
    //...
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
Paths paths = new Paths(Arrays.asList(
        new Path("c:\\\\test"),
        new Path("c:\\\\test1"),
        new Path("c:\\\\test1")));
```

Answer (score -1):

Before running the step to compare classes, try using this if statement or printing out the object's class type in code.

```
if((obj instanceof Path) == false)
    return false;
```

I see you are trying to remove a singleton from a list.  The "singleton" method returns a Set object, which may be obj's type and why comparing a Path object to a Set object will return false.  However, it may not be the line that you are referencing that is failing.
Please provide the declarations of all referenced objects and the full equals method of your Path object.